# Is $f$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by, $$f=\begin{cases}x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}& x\ne0 \\0& x=0\end{cases}$$Examine the uniform continuity of $f$.

I have tried to use the sequential criteria to prove this, but couldn't. The $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition also seems to get me nowhere. How can I prove (or disprove) this problem.

By the way, if we use the following two results then the proof becomes easy.

> **Result 1.** If $f, g: D(\subseteq\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ be two uniformly continuous function then $f\circ g$ is also uniformly continuous function.
>
> **Result 2.** If $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$$then $f$ is also uniformly continuous function.

But I am looking for a proof from the definition.

Comment: Result 2 does not apply since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}x\sin(1/x)=1$. It's not clear how Result 1 applies either since $1/x$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: For Result 2. to holdit is enough that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)$ exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be difficult if you only allow to use the definition. However, if you accept the use of the following fact combined with the definition, then there is a solution.

Recall the following fact: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on every closed and bounded interval $I$.

Now it is clear that your function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$.

For $x,y\notin[-1,1]$, recall the following facts
$$|\sin a|\leq |a|,\quad \sin a-\sin b=2\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\sin\frac{a-b}{2},\quad\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$$
Thus
$$\begin{aligned}
&\left| x\sin\frac{1}{x}-y\sin\frac{1}{y}\right|\\
\leq &|x|\left|\sin\frac{1}{x}-\sin\frac{1}{y}\right|+|x-y|\left|\sin\frac{1}{y}\right|\\
\leq &|x|\left|2\sin\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}}{2}\cos\frac{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}{2}\right|+|x-y|\\
\leq &|x|\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|+|x-y|\\
\leq &\left|1+\frac{1}{|y|}\right||x-y|\\
\leq &2|x-y|
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

I will intuitively argue with you why the Result 2 should be true, so you may fill in the details to prove it.

First, closely inspect the notion of uniform continuity. Intuitively, it says that for every $\varepsilon$, there is an $\delta$ such that error $<\delta$ on any part of the domain cause error $<\varepsilon$ on the range.

That is, when you chop up the domain in thin slices, the function does not change much throughout a slice, and this maximum change holds for every slice.

From this, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)$ both exist, then for large $M$ the function is not changing very much over $(-\infty, -M]$ and $[M,+\infty)$. However, if you chop $[-M, M]$ up many times, you see $f$ isn't changing very much either - you may establish this by a good understanding of continuous functions over compact intervals.

The last detail is to *glue* these three domains to get a whole line. This is not very problematic, as we see by inspecting $[-2M, -M/2]$ and $[M/2, 2M]$, but make sure you write this step properly in a formal proof. Thus we establish that by an approppriate chopping of the real line, $f$ doesn't change much in every slice. We are done.

I encourage you to convert these intuitive arguments into a full proof, and even posting it as your own answer.